# Copy specific table from one Wordpress database to another

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I recently discovered that my wordpress website (and it's database) were compromised and corrupted for reasons that are unknown (according to my webhost, iPower). No local backups exist, and iPower has no backups to restore to.

Certain essential parts of the site database are missing, but many of the most important tables still exist. To be specific, in my case the table 'wp_hlrv_options' was damaged, but all the other tables are intact.

My question is: would it be possible to 'copy' the 'wp_hlrv_options' table from a fresh wordpress install to my goofed up database?

If that isn't possible, I imagine I could copy the other intact tables to the fresh install, but simply replacing 'wp_hlrv_options' seems like it would be the fastest/easiest way to go about salvaging my site.

Any feedback/suggestions would be awesome, and I'm happy to provide more specific details if necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup the database (as is), especially the table you are going to import, and then just try it. In the worst case you will just empty the database and reimport it from backed-up data.